# Why do TaskFactory.FromAsync() overloads require a state object to be supplied?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

As detailed in the [TPL and Traditional .NET Framework Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx) MSDN article and Stephen Toub's [Tasks and the APM Pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/09/9716439.aspx) blog post, the [`TaskFactory.FromAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) and [`TaskFactory<TResult>.FromAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321472.aspx) methods can be used to adapt Begin*() and End*() APIs conforming to the APM pattern for use with the Task Parallel Library.

*Below I will address only the `TaskFactory<TResult>.FromAsync()` overloads, as my question does not depend on whether the APM-conforming APIs result in a value.*

There are three overloads that accept an `IAsyncResult` object, namely:

- `FromAsync(IAsyncResult, Func<IAsyncResult, TResult>)`
- `FromAsync(IAsyncResult, Func<IAsyncResult, TResult>, TaskCreationOptions)`
- `FromAsync(IAsyncResult, Func<IAsyncResult, TResult>, TaskCreationOptions, TaskScheduler)`

I understand that these APIs are useful in scenarios where the Begin*() API method takes more than three parameters in addition to the `AsyncCallback` and state `object` (e.g. [Too many arguments in `BeginXXX` for `FromAsync`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15582450/196844)), or when the `Begin*()` API does not fully conform to the APM pattern because it does not take a state `object` parameter (e.g. [How can I use the AsyncCTP with an TFS APM Method (`Query.Begin`/`EndQuery`)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7518139/196844)).

What I don't understand is why the remaining overloads (e.g. `FromAsync(Func<AsyncCallback, Object, IAsyncResult>, Func<IAsyncResult, TResult>, Object)`) all require a state `object` to be supplied.  This state `object` is passed to the `Begin*()` API, but in the APM pattern, the state `object` is for private use by the caller.  So, it shouldn't matter what state `object` is passed to the `Begin*()` API by `FromAsync()`.

The MSDN article linked above has a section titled "Providing Custom State Data" which recommends capturing any required state in a continuation delegate and passing `null` for the state object to `FromAsync()`.  However, this does not explain why the `FromAsync()` methods require a state object to be given.

Why is a state `object` required to be passed when it is not accessible to the returned `Task<TResult>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, If you [follow the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskFactory.cs,c24103836969a934) you can see that the state can indeed be accessed from the `Task` instance using the (not so surprisingly named) [`Task.AsyncState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321461(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync<TResult>(...);
object state = task.AsyncState
```

This property holds the state of the asynchronous operation in other scenarios as well, like `Task.Factory.StartNew`:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => { }, "bar");
Console.WriteLine(task.AsyncState); // prints "bar"
```

So, since the state is accessible, it's expected to be able to pass a state in as a parameter and doubling the API once with the state parameter and once without doesn't sound like the better option. Especially when you can just pass in `null`.

Comment: Ah!  Did not know about `Task.AsyncState`.  I presume that it was added specifically for this purpose?  Are there any other uses of `Task.AsyncState`?

Comment: @DanielTrebbien I doubt it. It's a general concept used in performance-heavy scenarios. It's also used when you pass in a state in `Task.Factory.StartNew` for example.

Comment: The APM contract also has a `state` argument. It's only logical that this API would account for that.

Comment: @PauloMorgado of course. That's what the question is about.